# Ionic 2 Server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, ionic2

When I run my Ionic app (with `ionic serve` on cmd), I get this error on console:

> http://localhost:8100/assets/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=3.0.0-alpha.3
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

[image]

Comment: Put the fonts inside src/assets/fonts/font-awesome.css and change css location in src/index.html

Comment: i just update my error, i don't see any ionicons.woff2 file like that

Comment: Its a rc0 problem just delete www/build/assets/fonts and src/assets/fonts

Comment: to delete the folder?